# css not working when request .php like "/example.php/" but display the content

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess, url

im developing an script in php, and i separate each section as .php file to got them in include() php function.

so after i separate

1. header.php
2. footer.php
3. etc..

everything fine in each folder with include(), and as a example if you want to view the file in browser:

http://localhost/yourfile.php fine!

http://localhost/yourfile.php/ bad!

when u add (/) it show the content of yourfile.php but without css!

i tryed to add **.htaccess** with value

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /snapchat/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and the header  values

```html
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assest/css/styles.css">
<!-- javascript files -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha384-tsQFqpEReu7ZLhBV2VZlAu7zcOV+rXbYlF2cqB8txI/8aZajjp4Bqd+V6D5IgvKT" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assest/js/main.js"></script>
<!-- end imported files -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<title>title</title>
</head>
<body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your css link is relative, e.g `assest/css/styles.css` , so browser try to download styles from `http://localhost/yourfile.php/assest/css/styles.css`

If you change the pass of css to this `/assest/css/styles.css`, browser will load styles from  `http://localhost/assest/css/styles.css` (consider `/`  at the start of the path)

Answer (score 0):

since you are URL re-writing, you need to add a trailing slash before your style sheets

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assest/js/main.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assest/css/styles.css">
```

that will solve your problem!